# Java NullPointerException when using scanner.hasNext();

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, java.util.scanner

I came up with the following code to read information from a file:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Reader {

    private Scanner s;

    public void openFile() {
        try {
            s = new Scanner(new File("file.txt"));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("File not found. Try again.");
        }
    }

    public void readFile() {
        while (s.hasNext()) {
            String a = s.next();
            String b = s.next();
            String c = s.next();
            int d = s.nextInt();
            int e = s.nextInt();
            int f = s.nextInt();
    }

    public void closeFile() {
        s.close();
    }

}
```

However, I get a NullPointer error on the (***while (s.hasNext())***) line and can't find a solution.

I'm working in Eclipse and the file I'm reading from is imported correctly into the project so that should not be an issue.

EDIT:

The way I access the methods:

```
public class Tester {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Reader read = new Reader();

        read.openFile();
        read.readFile();
        read.closeFile();

    }

}
```

Comment: Did you call `openFile()` before `readFile()`?

Comment: and did that pass without printing "File not found"?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show how you're calling `openFile` and `readFile`

Comment: As a note, this class makes little sense because the only way to properly call its methods is `open` - `read` -  `close`. You may as well just enforce that order by putting the code into a single method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the statement where NPE throws, `while (s.hasNext())`, it's most probable that the `s` is null pointer, you can add `System.out.println(s);` before that statement to double confirm it.

And for the reason why the `s` is `null`, there are two possible reasons:

1. You didn't invoke `openFile` before `readFile`
2. Exception is thrown when you open the file. The `s` is only a declaration and hasn't pointed to any object yet.

Maybe for a better practice, you can assert whether a instance is `null` or not before invoking its method. And as per my understanding, the `readFile` depends on the result of `openFile`, maybe you can set return value of `openFile` like a boolean value and check the return value before further open file operation. It's impossible to read a file which can't be even open, right?

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Reader {

    private Scanner s;

    public boolean openFile() {
        try {
            s = new Scanner(new File("file.txt"));
            return true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("File not found. Try again.");
            return false;
        }
    }

    public void readFile() {
        while (s.hasNext()) {
            String a = s.next();
            String b = s.next();
            String c = s.next();
            int d = s.nextInt();
            int e = s.nextInt();
            int f = s.nextInt();
     }
}
```

The invoker can do something like below:

```
Reader reader = new Reader();
if (reader.openFile())
    reader.readFile();
```

Comment: I just tried your solution. When using the invoker the way you wrote it, as long as I don't use .closeFile() afterward, the NLE is gone, but only "File not found. Try again." is printed. However, if I use .closeFile() afterward, it throws a NLE again.

Comment: @flowz0r that's because you try to close something that isn't open. Your problem is your instantiation of your reader has a problem. Instead of a simple print statement, print the stacktrace there, it'll be more clear about what is going wrong

Comment: @Stultuske, yep. That was it. Everything works fine now! Cheers.

Comment: Your `closeFile`  also used `s` instance, right? How can you close a file which hasn't even been open? The "File not found. Try again." message means the code failed to initiated the Scanner and it's still null. So if you invoke the method inside `s`, you will meet NPE issue.

Comment: @Eugene Everything works fine now. When re-writing this with your solution I accidentally placed the .txt into another project. Your solution is fine and the code works properly now, just a little mistake by me. Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: @flowz0r Glad it helps.